# como obtener el ultimo dia de la semana que estuvo activo de un objecto de booleanos

Tags: javascript, array

```
const daySchedule = {
  0: false,
  1: false,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  4: true,
  5: true,
  6: false,
};
```

Necesito obtener el ultimo día que estuvo con el booleano en true dado un numero recibido
en este caso si llamara a mi función `gestLastDay(6)` mandando como argumento el numero 6 (sabado) debería de tener como resultado el día 5.

Si le dijera a mi función que el día actual es el 0 (domingo) debería de retornar 5.

```
const getLastDay = (day) => {
  let lastActiveDay;
  for (let i = day; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (daySchedule[i]) {
      lastActiveDay = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (lastActiveDay === undefined) {
    for (let i = 6; i > day; i--) {
      if (daySchedule[i]) {
        lastActiveDay = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return lastActiveDay;
}
```

Comment: cambiar `day` por `day - 1`

Answer (score 1):

**solucion**

```
const getLastDay =(day)=>{
  let lastActiveDay;
  for (let i = day - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (daySchedule[i]) {
      lastActiveDay = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (lastActiveDay === undefined) {
    for (let i = 6; i > day - 1; i--) {
      if (daySchedule[i]) {
        lastActiveDay = i;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return lastActiveDay;
}
```

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Piénsalo como algo para los que tengan un problema similar :)

Comment: ¿Por qué es la solución? ¿Qué estaba mal, qué se corrigió? ¿A quién le sirve esta respuesta?